# how to update value of a firebase column on event success

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the RazorPay API in my android app and I want to update the value of a particular user's "count" on successful payment. So I put the following code for the updation of the count in the onSucessfulPayment() method but even on the account of successful payment, the value of count is not getting updated.

My database is like:

Userdata:

___user1

_____name

_____age

_____count

___user2

Here's the code:

```html
public class Payment extends AppCompatActivity implements PaymentResultListener {

    EditText value;
    Button pay;
    int payamount;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference db;
    int d;
    String da;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);

        value = findViewById(R.id.input);
        pay = findViewById(R.id.razorpay);

        pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //define method for payment process
                startPayment();
            }
        });
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("db");
        SharedPreferences sharedPreference;
        users u = new users();
        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<users> u = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot ds1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    users md = dataSnapshot.getValue(users.class);
                    d = md.getCount();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });

    }

    private void startPayment() {
        pa = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString());         Checkout checkout = new Checkout();
        final Activity activity = this;
        try {
            JSONObject options = new JSONObject();
           
            options.put("amount", payamount*100);
            checkout.open(activity, options);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPaymentSuccess(String s) {

        try {
            Toast.makeText(Payment.this, "Your payment is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            da = da + pa;
            da = Integer.toString(da);
            FirebaseAuth fa;
            FirebaseUser u;
            fa = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            u = fa.getCurrentUser();
            String uid = u.getUid();
            db.child(u.getUid()).child("count").setValue(da);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentError(int i, String s) {
        Toast.makeText(Payment.this,"Your payment is unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Might want to add a Success listener in order to check if a write is successful, you also can use a transaction if its key to your business logic

```
    db.child(u.getUid()).child("count").setValue(da)  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        // Write was successful!
        // ...
    }
})
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        // Write failed
        // ...
    }
});
```

OR Make it a transaction by calling start transaction on "count" reference

Comment: can you please elaborate I'm new to android and firebase. I have added the success listener like you said but still the value doesnt get updated , please elaborate the transaction part.

Comment: you might want to check if the onFailure listener is being called and check what exception is being called try adding a log statement in both the onSuccess and onFailure methods and see whats getting logged. Log the exception so that you can search for it. Sometimes it can be down to the most basic error such as database rules not being enabled. TRY LOGGING THE EXCEPTION.

Comment: Transactions are useful to makesure that all your db calls are succesful. They will roll back to previous state if any exception is raised during the call. they can be used when you have multiple db calls which are critical and must happen in an order. Do read the doccumentation you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `onSuccessListener` as in the other answers. You don't need `onFailureListener` as the code will always be stuck there because there is no exception. Firebase is not throwing an error. It will just try to update the data whenever an Internet connection will be available.

Rather you can combine `CheckNetworkState` with this to avoid errors.